# What is a shadowed register file and what is a narrow register file?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I'm reading [an architecture specification for an OpenRISC](https://github.com/openrisc/doc/blob/master/openrisc-arch-1.1-rev0.pdf). Section 2.1 has a description of features. One of them is the following:

> Shadowed or single 32-entry or narrow 16-entry general purpose
>   register file.

What is a shadowed register file? What is a narrow register file?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422246/what-are-shadow-registers-and-how-are-they-used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shadow register file is a set of registers that has the same names as the 'normal' set of registers, but gets used only in certain modes.  For example, when handling interrupts, a set of shadow registers might be used so that the interrupt handler doesn't need to perform a bunch of work to save context.

For example, from 4.4 of the linked document:

> An implementation may have several sets of GPRs and use them as shadow registers, switching between them whenever a new exception occurs

ARM uses shadow registers for this in some of their architectures.

I believe (but I'm not sure) that in the phrase "single 32-entry or narrow 16-entry general purpose register file":

- "single" means that an implementation of OpenRISC is not required to have a shadow register file
- "narrow" means that an OpenRISC implementation is permitted to support only 16 GPRs instead of the usual set of 32